# Is it possible to expand a tuple expression into a comma-separated list in a Rust syntax extension with quasiquoting?

Tags: macros, rust

I'm writing a syntax extension for Rust and I want to generate a tuple expression using `quote_expr!`. What I do now is:

```
let tuple_values: Vec<P<Expr>> = ...;
let tuple_expr: cx.expr_tuple(sp, tuple_value);
let e = quote_stmt!(cx, let v = $tuple_expr);
```

It works, but I want to write something like:

```
let tuple_values: Vec<P<Expr>> = ...;
let e = quote_stmt!(cx, let v = ($tuple_values..));
```

i.e. expand `tuple_values` into a comma-separated list. Is it possible?